# Should I ask a new question about the same error?

Tags: discussion

I had a error in my MySQL query. I asked a question, thankfully got an alternative way to do what I needed to do in an answer, and got the job done.

I am creating another database, with a few tables with foreign keys (that was the erroneous part in the first database), and all of them are bringing up that error. I am trying to do it with the alternative way as well, but the error doesn't just go away.

*There are a few questions addressing this bug on this Stack Overflow, I tried the solutions but nothing seems to work for me.*

**So should I ask a new question and refer to my previous question (as well as the other questions whose solutions I have tried) or should I just edit my previous question?**

P.S. *My yesterday's question has already got quite lengthy after the edits, so I won't like to edit it any more.*

---

**Edit:-** Response to the comment by Louis:

The question in question is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221314/mysql-error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno150-again-in-all-the-forei). My yesterday's question is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204556/why-am-i-getting-error-code-1005-can-t-create-c-errno-150-mysql?noredirect=1#comment35517032_23204556).

Comment: Unless my eyes deceive me this question here does not contain a link to the question you are asking about. It would be useful, I think, to see what the question in question is.

Comment: @Louis Just added it in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ask a new question.

The new problem is different. Your first question was solved using the methods provided. Your second question cannot be solved using those same methods, according to your statement. If you edit your original question to add the scope of this new issue, any previously-correct answer is now at least partially incorrect.

Be sure that you have done all of your research before posting. Are there any details that you may have overlooked when applying the solution to the new problem? Have you addressed all of the variables? If you have been thorough in attempting to solve the issue on your own, you should make a new post to avoid creating confusion on the original one.